# Hanning window values doesnt match in Python and Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I've been working in a low-pass filter that should be filter a .wav file using Hann window and some custom digital filters.

I did the whole code for Matlab and today I did write it in Python, but when I started to compare the values of the hann function in Python x Matlab it doesnt have ANYTHING to do...

```py
#python hanning
hanning(10)
# array([0., 0.11697778, 0.41317591, 0.75, 0.96984631, 0.96984631, 0.75, 0.41317591, 0.11697778, 0.])
```

```matlab
%matlab hanning
hanning(10)
% ans =
%    0.0794
%    0.2923
%    0.5712
%    0.8274
%    0.9797
%    0.9797
%    0.8274
%    0.5712
%    0.2923
%    0.0794
```

Comment: Please include your code in both languages.

Comment: MATLAB Signal Processing Toolbox has `hann` and `hamming`. MATLAB does not have a `hanning` function. Is this a function you wrote yourself, or did you get it from some other 3rd party source?

Comment: Actually, your MATLAB output looks like it is from `hamming`, is that what you used?

Comment: @Cris MATLAB does `hanning`, it's just not documented, and probably deprecated

Comment: @Luis: Well, if I can't find it in the docs, it doesn't exist! :p

Comment: @CrisLuengo I rarely use the docs. `help hanning` or `open hanning` are quicker :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;WR:**

They use different definitions. Matlab's equivalent to Numpy's `hanning` is `hann`, not `hanning`.

---

In **Matlab**, `hanning(n)` creates a symmetric window. From the code in file `hanning.m`, for even `n` the first half of this window is computed as

```
m = n/2;
w = .5*(1 - cos(2*pi*(1:m).'/(n+1)))
```

and then the full window is obtained as `w = [w; w(end:-1:1)]`. Except for numerical precision issues (which are probably the reason why Matlab computes only one half and then mirrors it), this is equivalent to

```
w = .5*(1 - cos(2*pi*(1:n).'/(n+1)));
```

In **Numpy**, according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hanning.html), the formula is different. In Matlab syntax it corresponds to

```
w = .5*(1 - cos(2*pi*(0:n-1).'/(n-1)));
```

which is Matlab's `hann(n)`, as described in its [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/hann.html).

Answer (score 3):

In `scipy.signal`, the function `hanning` is deprecated.  The function to use is `scipy.signal.hann`.

`numpy.hanning` and `scipy.signal.hann` compute the same window.
The functions include the zero values at the end of the window.  To match the output of the Matlab function that you show in the question, add 2 to the argument of `scipy.signal.hann`, and then discard the zeros at the ends:

```
In [1]: from scipy.signal import hann                                                                                                                                           

In [2]: hann(12)                                                                                                                                                                
Out[2]: 
array([0.        , 0.07937323, 0.29229249, 0.57115742, 0.82743037,
       0.97974649, 0.97974649, 0.82743037, 0.57115742, 0.29229249,
       0.07937323, 0.        ])

In [3]: hann(12)[1:-1]                                                                                                                                                          
Out[3]: 
array([0.07937323, 0.29229249, 0.57115742, 0.82743037, 0.97974649,
       0.97974649, 0.82743037, 0.57115742, 0.29229249, 0.07937323])
```